# golang tgbotapi v5 send sticker

Tags: go

I'm writing a small go bot. I took this library https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5@v5.5.1 and while it was version 4 everything worked fine for sending stickers the following code worked:

```
bot.Send(tgbotapi.NewStickerShare(update.Message.Chat.ID, "hereIsTheIDOfTheSticker"))
```

But when I decided to upgrade to version 5, the stickers broke. And now I can't figure out how to send them. Can someone help with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way that the library are using it has changed.

The function `NewStickerShare` doesn't exists any more. instead, you need to use the new function called [`NewSticker`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5@v5.5.1#NewSticker):

- The `NewSticker` function accepts two parameters:

  - chatID `int64`
  - file [`RequestFileData`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5#RequestFileData)
- As you can see, the [`RequestFileData`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5#RequestFileData) interface has the following contract:

```golang
type RequestFileData interface {
    NeedsUpload() bool
    UploadData() (string, io.Reader, error)
    SendData() string
}
```

- We need to implement this contract for your Sticker **OR** find an already structure implemented by the library. Probably, the library provide something to us, and we have now the [`FileID`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5#FileID) structure implementing these methods.

From that, once you want to send the ID of the Sticker, you need to develop something like that:

```golang
stickerID := tgbotapi.FileID("hereIsTheIDOfTheSticker")
msg := tgbotapi.NewSticker(update.Message.Chat.ID, stickerID)
bot.Send(msg)
```

If you need more structures that implements the [`RequestFileData`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5#RequestFileData) contract, the library provide some of them: [`FilePath`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5#FilePath), [`FileReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5#FileReader) ... Each one has your own goal.

I hope it can help you :)

Comment: wow It works. Thank you. I'm new in go, so please forgive me for stupid questions. I am learning with all my might.

Comment: @Guskuskudu Good! :D No worry, doesn't exist stupid questions. I hope you can go ahead with your project and learn a lot of Go :) See you soon and welcome to our community.